# Cannot connect webapp to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, centos

I'm trying to publish my asp.net core app onto a linux (Centos) machine. This is just a local virtual machine while I iron out the issues.

I've gone through all the steps I think are needed, but when I try to run the app, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (28000: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres") ---> Npgsql.PostgresException: 28000: Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

For the life of me I cant work out whats going on. As this is just a VM test environment, I have set up every password (my user, root, both postgres passwords) the same. So its unlikely I am mixing them up.

The connection string I'm using is:

```
"User ID=postgres;Password=password;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=cp1;Pooling=true;"
```

The contents of my pg_hba.conf files are:
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
local   all             postgres                                peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

A few of the lines at the end where added by myself in desperation.

I'm running out of things to try. Can anyone suggest what might be causing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work this out. I had to remove the "ident" entries, not just add md5 entries.

As soon as I commented out the two ident entries, it started working.